# Using for loops over while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

How would one produce some code that counts up using a for loop as opposed to a while loop? My code is as follows;

```
def square():
    count = 1
    number = input("How far?")
    number = int(number)
    if number < 1:
        print ("broken")
    elif number >= 1:
        while count <= number:
            square = count*count
            print ("{0}*{0}={1}".format(count, square))
            count = count+1
square()
```

Comment: Did u read in Python documentation about `for` loops?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
def square():
    number = input("How far?")
    number = int(number)
    if number < 1:
        print ("broken")
    elif number >= 1:
        for count in range(1,number+1):
            square = count*count
            print ("{0}*{0}={1}".format(count, square))
square()
```

Using the line

```
for count in range(1,number+1):
```

`counts` iterates over the values `1,2,...,number`.

Answer (score 0):

U can do it with list comprehensions  like:

```
def square():
    number = int(input("How far?"))
    # range will be from 1 to number +1, and will proceed square for all
    return [val ** 2 for val in range (1, number+1)]

squares = square()
if not squares:
    print('broken')
# u can iterate over result even if list is empty(if u pass broken number)
for val in squares:
    print ("{0}*{0}={1}".format(count, square))
```